# Is reference to object still valid after its destruction and recreation in-place?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, in-place

what will happen to the reference to an object after destruction and creation in-place of that object? Will it be still valid or it is undefined behavior? Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int var;

public:
    A(int var) : var(var) {}

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << var;
    }
};

A obj(5);

void main()
{
    A& ref = obj;
    obj.~A();
    new (&obj) A(6);
    
    ref.foo();  // is this valid?
}
```

Comment: Specified in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#8, and it is likely that similar questions have been asked before.

Comment: Colour me surprised. That's the sort of thing I'd expect to "work", but be technically illegal. Nice to see the Standard canonizes it with a relatively short list of caveats.